# Retrieve image reference from MySQL database when selected radiobutton changes

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL database that stores the paths to images.

I would like the displayed image to change based on the selected radiobutton option. I am trying to use AJAX to update the the displayed image, but my understanding of this technology is very limited.

This is the radiobutton list and the image. A JS function is called when the selected element changes.

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../images/1.png" id="buildimage" />

<ul id="radio" class="input-list">
  <li>
    <input id="item-1" name="config-prod" value="1.00" type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
    <label for="item-1">Item 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-2" name="config-prod" value="2.00" type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
    <label for="item-2">Item 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-3" name="config-prod" value="3.00" type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
    <label for="item-3">Item 3</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the function updateImage:

```
<script>
    function updateImage(caseid) {
        selectmenuID = document.getElementById(caseid);

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("buildimage").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "displayImage.php", true);
        xhttp.send("id='selectmenuID'");

    }

</script>
```

PHP file that retrieves the path:

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

$id = $_GET["id"];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT link FROM cases WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result['image'] ).'"/>';

?>
```

The problem I have is that I do not understand how to use AJAX to call the PHP file passing the selected element ID, and then change the src file path based on the response.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: You should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Also, use `console.log()` to debug your javscript code and `var_dump()` or xdebug for php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to use `xhttp.responseText` instead of `this.responseText` to get the response from the server.

Then, you should directly replace the `src` attribute of the image instead of trying to replace its html :

```
document.getElementById("buildimage").src = xhttp.responseText;
```

serverside :

```
echo $result['image'];
```

You also have to replace this line :

```
xhttp.send("id='selectmenuID'");
```

by this :

```
xhttp.send("id="+selectmenuID);
```